# How to make two NaN as NaN after the operation instead of making it zero?

Tags: pandas

I have the following data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {
    'ID':[1,2,3],
    'W1':[5,6,7],
    'W2':[9, np.nan,10],
    'w3':[11,np.nan,np.nan]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df


  ID    W1  W2   w3
0   1   5   9.0    11.0
1   2   6   NaN     NaN
2   3   7   10.0    NaN
```

I am doing the following operations

```
df['Sum1'] = (df[['W1','W2']]).sum(axis = 1)/2
df['Sum2'] = (df[['W2','w3']]).sum(axis = 1)/2


    ID  W1  W2      w3  Sum1    Sum2
0   1   5   9.0    11.0 7.0     10.0
1   2   6   NaN     NaN 3.0     0.0
2   3   7   10.0    NaN 8.5     5.0
```

How to make Sum2 of ID "2" as **NaN** instead of **0** after doing the above operations??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter `min_count=1` to [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

> **min_count** : int, default **0**
> The required number of valid values to perform the operation. If fewer than min_count non-NA values are present the result will be NA.
>
> New in version 0.22.0: Added with the default being 0. This means the sum of an all-NA or empty Series is 0, and the product of an all-NA or empty Series is 1.

```
df['Sum1'] = (df[['W1','W2']]).sum(axis = 1, min_count=1)/2
df['Sum2'] = (df[['W2','w3']]).sum(axis = 1, min_count=1)/2

print (df)
   ID  W1    W2    w3  Sum1  Sum2
0   1   5   9.0  11.0   7.0  10.0
1   2   6   NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN
2   3   7  10.0   NaN   8.5   5.0
```

But is seems you need `mean`s - then it working like need:

```
df['Sum1'] = (df[['W1','W2']]).mean(axis = 1)
df['Sum2'] = (df[['W2','w3']]).mean(axis = 1)

print (df)
   ID  W1    W2    w3  Sum1  Sum2
0   1   5   9.0  11.0   7.0  10.0
1   2   6   NaN   NaN   6.0   NaN
2   3   7  10.0   NaN   8.5  10.0
```

Comment: first answer works for me! What is min_count=1 means? Some time I may have three or four columns will the  answer work for that?

Comment: @panda - I think yes, if multiple columns filled only `NaNs` per rows, it working same way.