# How to keep NaN in pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Looking to preserve NaN values when changing the shape of the dataframe.

These two questions may be related:

- [How to preserve NaN instead of filling with zeros in pivot table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742166/)
- [How to make two NaN as NaN after the operation instead of making it zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626176/)

but not been able to use the answers provided - can I set a min count for np.sum somehow?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([['Y1', np.nan], ['Y2', np.nan], ['Y1', 6], ['Y2',8]], columns=['A', 'B'], index=['1988-01-01','1988-01-01', '1988-01-04', '1988-01-04'])
df.index.name = 'Date'
df

pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='B', index=['Date'], columns=['A'],aggfunc=np.sum)
pivot_df
```

The output is:

```
A   Y1  Y2
Date        
1988-01-01  0.0 0.0
1988-01-04  6.0 8.0
```

and the desired output is:

```
A   Y1  Y2
Date        
1988-01-01  NaN NaN
1988-01-04  6.0 8.0
```

Comment: Try: `pd.pivot_table(df, values='B', index=['Date'], columns=['A'], aggfunc='sum').replace(0, np.NaN)`

Comment: @Erfan what if there are values that actually *should* be `0`?

Comment: That's a matter of interpretation if you're using `sum`. There's no actual `0`. It's the sum that counts up to `0`. @user3483203

Comment: @user3483203 that is the issue (why zeros must not be introduced by nan values)

Comment: @erfan Not what I meant.  What if both rows for `1988-01-04` are `0`, the sum *should* be zero, but you're comment would replace that with `NaN`.  I'm not sure what you mean by "no actual 0"

Comment: Then I would not have a problem to interpret them as `NaN` , but that's up to OP @user3483203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no duplicate entries, use `set_index` + `unstack`

```
df.set_index('A', append=True)['B'].unstack(-1)
```

```
A            Y1   Y2
Date
1988-01-01  NaN  NaN
1988-01-04  6.0  8.0
```

---

If you have duplicates, use a `groupby` with `min_count`

```
>> df

             A    B
Date
1988-01-01  Y1  NaN
1988-01-01  Y2  NaN
1988-01-04  Y1  6.0
1988-01-04  Y2  8.0
1988-01-01  Y1  NaN
1988-01-01  Y2  NaN
1988-01-04  Y1  6.0
1988-01-04  Y2  8.0
```

```
df.set_index('A', append=True).groupby(level=[0, 1])['B'].sum(min_count=1).unstack(-1)
```

```
A             Y1    Y2
Date
1988-01-01   NaN   NaN
1988-01-04  12.0  16.0
```

Comment: Feels natural to use the first solution in my case (when no aggregation is desired) :thumbsup:

Answer (score 3):

From the helpful comments the following solution meets my requirements:

```py
pivot_df_2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='B', index=['Date'], columns=['A'],aggfunc=min, dropna=False)
pivot_df_2
```

Values are supposed to be unique per slot so replacing the sum function with a min function shouldn't make a difference (in my case)

Comment: If values are unique per slot, use `df.set_index('A', append=True)['B'].unstack(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would resolve by `groupby`:

```
(df.groupby(['Date', 'A']).B
   .apply(lambda x: np.nan if x.isna().all() else x.sum())
   .unstack('A')
)
```

output:

```
A            Y1   Y2
Date                
1988-01-01  NaN  NaN
1988-01-04  6.0  8.0
```

Change `isna().all()` to `isna().any()` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to count the values, and drop when 0 (or less than the expected count):

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='B', index=['Date'], columns=['A'],
                          aggfunc=['sum','count'])

# build the mask from count
mask = (pivot_df.xs('count', axis=1) == 0)   # or ...<min_limit

#build the actual pivot_df from sum
pivot_df = pivot_df.xs('sum', axis=1)

# and reset to NaN when not enough values
pivot_df[mask] = np.nan
```

It gives as expected:

```
A            Y1   Y2
Date                
1988-01-01  NaN  NaN
1988-01-04  6.0  8.0
```

This one will give sensible result when you sum more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to keep NaN values, and I also wanted to keep using the `pivot_table` function. So here is my solution:

```py
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    values='B',
    index=['Date'],
    columns=['A'],
    aggfunc=lambda x: x.sum(min_count=1),
    dropna=False
)

The downside is that this is less efficient in terms of computation time.
```

Comment: I needed to add `dropna=False` to this solution to make sure it displays the 1988-01-01 date.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add `'dropna= False'` to your pivot_table function?

Comment: This isn't solve the problem. The dropna=False will just prevents the NaN total removal from the pivot table. Here we want to not only keep the NaN but also prevent that the pivot_table method transforms it into 0, which would be the normal behaviour.