# Empty Index in Pivot Tabele Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have I have a table that I load as a dataframe with the help of a pandas.
Next, I would like to create a PivotTable
table:

| Name | Lang | skills |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | http | 1 |
| Cristiano | css | 2 |
| John | js | 3 |
| Piter | http | 4 |
| Michael | css | 3 |
| Cristiano | js | 2 |
| John | http | 1 |
| Piter | css | 4 |
| NaN | js | 1 |

I use the command

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values= 'skills', index = 'Name', columns= 'Lang', aggfunc ='sum')
```

And I have:

| Name | css | http | js |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cristiano | 2 | nan | 2 |
| John | nan | 1 | 3 |
| Michael | 3 | 1 | nan |
| Piter | 4 | 4 | nan |

The problem is, I would like the Empty index to be included as well
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `nan` with string like 'Other', then do the operation:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

data_string = """Name   Lang    skills
Michael http    1
Cristiano   css 2
John    js  3
Piter   http    4
Michael css 3
Cristiano   js  2
John    http    1
Piter   css 4
NaN js  1
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_string), sep='\s+')
df['Name'].replace(np.nan, 'Other', inplace=True)

pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='skills', index='Name', columns='Lang', aggfunc='sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values= 'skills', dropna=False, index = 'Name', columns= 'Lang', aggfunc ='sum')
```

Comment: You can check out this post if above solution doesn't work
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890105/how-to-keep-nan-in-pivot-table)